# How to correctly group columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, multiple-columns

I have a Data Frame with this columns:

```
DF.head():
Email           Month    Year
abc@Mail.com      1      2018
abb@Mail.com      1      2018
abd@Mail.com      2      2019
     .   
     .
abbb@Mail.com     6      2019
```

What I want to do is to get the total of email adresses in each month for both years 2018 and 2019 (knowing that I don't need to filter, since I have only this two years).

This is what I've done, but I want to make sure that this is right:

```
 Stats = DF.groupby(['Year','Month'])['Email'].count()
```

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

It depends what need.

If need exclude missing values or missing values not exist in `Email` column, your solution is right, use [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
Stats = DF.groupby(['Year','Month'])['Email'].count()
```

If need count all groups also with missing values (if exist) use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
Stats = DF.groupby(['Year','Month']).size()
```